# How do I Put my HighCharts DataLabels *Above* the Bar?

Tags: highcharts

I've got a HighChart bar chart with a whole ton of options, and it works perfectly except for one minor issue.  According to all the documentation I've found, if I have a plotOptions of :

```
{
    cursor: "pointer",
    column:{
        dataLabels: {
            color: "#4572A7",
            enabled: true,
            style: {"fontWeight":"bold"}
        },
        inside: false,
        point:{"events":{}},
        stacking: 'normal',
   }
}
```

I should get a caption above each bar in my bar chart.  However, instead of appearing above each bar, these captions are being rendered in the center of the bar.  I'm sure I'm just missing one key option or something, but I haven't been able to figure out what that option is ... do any HighCharts experts out there happen to know?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the option I was missing was `verticalAlign`; when I added that to my dataLabels options (with a value of "top") it fixed things ... well mostly.  I also had to add a `y` option of "-10" to actually get the labels to be above the bar.

The funny thing is, I have the code for an old version of the chart, and it didn't have a `verticalAlign` option at all, but it showed its labels above the bar.  I guess some other option that I'm using in my version made the `verticalAlign` necessary.

In any case, I'm leaving this self-conversation behind in case someone else runs in to this same problem.